# How does Binding parameters prevent Sql Injection?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

In PHP, I've found a few methods to prevent Sql Injection. Binding parameters is one of them. But I'm unable to find a complete explanation of how binding parameters actually prevent Sql Injection. I was of the notion that binding parameters simply save time in binding different data to the same Sql statement. How does prevention of Sql injection come into picture?

Comment: I recommend reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Here is a thorough explanation that is exactly addressing your confusion, [The Hitchhiker's Guide to SQL Injection prevention::Prepared statemens](https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection#prepared)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think a *simple example* will explain you the thing:

```
  "select * from myTable where name = " + condition;
```

imagine that user input as a `condition` is

```
  '123'; delete from myTable; commit;
```

what happens then? the query executed will be

```
  select * from myTable where name = '123'; delete from myTable; commit;
```

or actually we have *three* queries with disastrous consequences:

```
  select * from myTable where name = '123';
  
  delete from myTable; 
  
  commit;
```

in case of bind variables

```
  "select * from myTable where name = @prmName"
```

whatever user input is it'll be *one and only one* query and the weird input above will always be treated as a *string*, not as a *part of query*. The outcome will be (most probably) an *empty cursor*, since there're no `name`s within `myTable` like

```
  "'123'; delete from myTable; commit;"
```

Comment: Just the explanation I needed which I was unable to get anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: @Mithil Bhoras: you're welcome!